# How to take a user input of various lengths for RODBC sqlQuery

Tags: r

So currently I am working on writing a function that starts by querying a database, currently I have to manually change the SQL Query that I have.  It looks like:

```
sqlQuery(db_query, 'SELECT * From my_db Where db_date = '2019/12/17' AND (ItemType = 1 or ItemType=2)')
```

My first questions is how do I make it to where I can take the date as a manual input as a part of the function.

My second question relates to the ItemType.  There are around 700 different options, And I need to be able to take as many of them as I can.  They aren't always going to be in order, or even consecutive numbers.  Here are a few examples of what it may end up looking like:

```
SELECT * From my_db Where db_date = '2019/12/17' AND (ItemType = 1 or ItemType=2)
```

or

```
SELECT * From my_db Where db_date = '2019/12/17' AND (ItemType = 50)
```

or

````
SELECT * From my_db Where db_date = '2019/12/17' AND (ItemType = 50 or ItemType=142 or ItemType=65 or ItemType=66)
```)
````

Comment: `ItemType in (1,2,3,4)` will make things way easier than using all those ORs

Comment: Well thats about to shorten up most of my queries, even outside of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sprintf` gives a lot of control to format strings.  First build the base SQL string and then load some test values

```
x <- "SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE db_date = '%s' AND (%s);"

d <- as.Date("2019/12/17")
c1 <- c(1, 2)
c2 <- c(50)
c3 <- c(50, 142, 65, 66)

> sprintf(x, format(d, "%Y/%m/%d"), paste("ItemType =", c1, collapse = " OR "))
[1] "SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE db_date = '2019/12/17' AND (ItemType = 1 OR ItemType = 2);"

> sprintf(x, format(d, "%Y/%m/%d"), paste("ItemType =", c2, collapse = " OR "))
[1] "SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE db_date = '2019/12/17' AND (ItemType = 50);"

> sprintf(x, format(d, "%Y/%m/%d"), paste("ItemType =", c3, collapse = " OR "))
[1] "SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE db_date = '2019/12/17' AND (ItemType = 50 OR ItemType = 142 OR ItemType = 65 OR ItemType = 66);"
```

Comment: Reconsider this string interpolation solution especially if values derive from user input. Recall the infamous [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/). OP can use [RODBCext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html) for parameterization.

Comment: Always a concern, but if you're sitting at a console you likely have access to everything be nefarious without using SQL injection.  On a side note the following `as.Date("2019/12/17;DROP TABLE X;")` returns `"2019-12-17"`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  And it is going to be user input to start, but when I get the chance (and before anyone else gets to use this), it'll all be wrapped inside a shiny app where you will select the numbers from a drop down instead of entering them.